# json schema for validating all child elements of a json Object node

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json document that i need to validate.

The json doc looks like this

```
    "ParentElement": { 

        "child1": {
          "property1": "hello",
          "property2": {
            }
          }
        },
          "child2": {
          "property1": "hello2",
          "property2": {
          }
        }
     }
```

i want all child elements of the ParentElement to have property1 and property2 as required elements.

required : ["property1", "property2"]

Note that i cannot use required inside the child elements because the name of the child elements differ and they are not fixed so the json schema wont have those names.

Tool i am using for validation: 
com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:2.2.62

Validation is pretty straightforward

schema.validate(AboveJSONDOC);

I need to define a schema that allows all the child elements to have those two required properties.

Comment: Hi @TejasPatel, can you please include the tools you are attempting to use to validate the JSON, along with any source code you've written or commands you are attempting to perform the validation?

Comment: Looks like you're using a library which only supports old versions of JSON Schema. Regardless, draft-4 supports `additionalProperties` and `patternProperties`. `patternProperties` is like `properties`, except that the keys are non anchored regexes (You need to anchor them yourself). https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.4.4 - Let me know if this isn't enough to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the validation schema for `child` object separately under definitions and refer that it to each child property that you want to validate.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "ParentElement": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "child1": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/child"
        },
        "child2": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/child"
        },
        "childN": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/child"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "ParentElement"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "child": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "property1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "property2": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "property1",
        "property2"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

When you don't know about the properties which may include in input JSON
you could use `patternProperties` to match properties using regular expressions.

Note that `.*` will accept every property. You could change it depending on your requirement.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "ParentElement": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        ".*": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/child"
        },
        "minProperties": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "ParentElement"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "child": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "property1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "property2": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "property1",
        "property2"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this works fine if i know the name of all the children beforehand (and therefore can set the schema for each one).
In my case, the schema doesn't know the name of the children. 
Hence, I was looking for some way so that the schema can define that all the children under this parent (no matter what the name ) should have a certain set of properties as required.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question. In this case, you can use `patternProperties`. I will update my answer accordingly.